# Opengl ES. Textures on cube. Rotating

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, textures, cube

I have cube with 6 diffrent textures. I wrote smiple animation. When I'm rotating my cube, everythings is ok, but after my animation my textures change them position.

In example.
I'm rotating my cube on the left. And im seeing right side but with texture from the front (after animation).

When the cube is ratating during animation im seeing correct texture, but after the texture is changing to texture from the front.

This is my code of draw method of cube.

```
 public void draw(GL10 gl) {
      gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
      gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
      gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer);

      // front
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize); 
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[front]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // left
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[left]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // back
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[back]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // right
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[right]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // top
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[top]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // bottom
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[bottom]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();


      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


   }
```

this is my update method

```
 public void updateRotation(GL10 gl) {

    if (currentProgress >= 1f) {
        return;
    }

    long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - getAnimStart();
    currentProgress = dt / (float) animTime;


    Log.d("progress", "" + currentProgress);
    if (currentProgress > 1f) {
        currentProgress = 1;
    } 
    else if(currentProgress < 0){
        currentProgress = 0;
    }

    currentProgress = interpolator.getInterpolation(currentProgress);

    setCurrentRotX((initialRotX + (targetRotX - initialRotX) * currentProgress));
    gl.glRotatef(-(float)((getCurrentRotX() * 180)/Math.PI), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    setCurrentRotY(initialRotY + (targetRotY - initialRotY) * currentProgress);
    gl.glRotatef(-(float)((getCurrentRotY() * 180)/Math.PI), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

}
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is but what matrix are you modifying with your glTranslatef and glRotatef calls?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I solved it. Don't remember what I did, but cube works fine and I closed this project long time ago:)